# Keeping ripe pears for canning later

Tags: fruit, food-preservation, canning

I picked my pears Labor day weekend like I always do but when I went to can them the following weekend only about 1/4 of them were ripe. Now the rest are all very ripe and there is no way I can get to canning them until Sunday (4 days). What is the best way to prevent them from being over ripe by then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put them in the fridge, and hope they stay good, or you can blanch them and freeze.

Blanching:

- Prepare the pears just like you would for canning (peel & cut).
- Dip the pear in hot water (or water with sugar) for about a minute.
- From the hot water, dip into an ice-bath.
- Plastic bag/container and into the freezer.

Comment: I had to go the refridgerator route as the other option would have taken too long (I am in the middle of a software conversion)

Comment: @MikeB, software conversions are a pain. Good luck!